# Do different units of explanatory variables affect p-values?

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value

In multiple linear regression, does including variables with different metering units and thus values very different in dimension/size affect statistical significance/ p-values?

In my model, a variable with large values (i.e. relatively large compared to the other included variables) exhibits a very small parameter estimate. Its p-value is very large, though sum of squares is large.

Now I am looking for an explanation and I guess it could be due to the different units of explanatory variables.

Comment: It would be strange if they did, don't you think?

Comment: @Aksakal That is true.  But people have actually seriously proposed statistical tests whose results change when values are rescaled.  It could make sense in cases where there is an intrinsic unit of measurement (counts are the clearest example of that).

Comment: @whuber, good point. You could change the units of measure from Pascal to decibel, and it's like log-transform, and this will change everything.

Comment: @Aksakal That's really a different issue: we should expect models of linear relationships among variables to change when the values are re-expressed in *nonlinear* ways. What I was referring to is that there are some procedures whose results will change even when the units of measurement of the variables are changed (linearly). Depending on [terminology](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132829), these are "non-invariant" or "non-equivariant" procedures.

Comment: @whuber, I don't think the count is a good example. In this case it's more like a sample size change. You don't observe the rate, you observe the counts. So changing the units of measure of count is really increase the sample size expressed in units of time. You go from per second to per minute, this really means your sample size increased 60 folds. This is not the trivial change from centimeter to meter when measuring length directly.

Comment: @Aksakal I am neither advocating nor disparaging this approach, only reporting that it exists. The application I saw concerns automated counts of very high values, such as ion counts in a mass spectrogram or counts of a Geiger counter. See http://info.ngwa.org/gwol/pdf/990564800.PDF for an account of that application and a rebuttal.  (I have publicly agreed with that rebuttal, BTW.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The units of variables affect the parameter estimates, but *not* the *p*-values.

Think of it this way: if you multiplied an entire variable in your dataset by 10, you could just divide the coefficient of that variable by 10, and get the exact same prediction for each data point. So the model will explain just as much of the variance as before.

However, it can be easier to interpret different aspects of your model if you "standardize" the units of each variable, for instance by dividing by the standard deviation of that variable. If you do this, then all of your variables will be unitless (and all of your coefficients will have the same units as your response variable), which means they can be compared on a single value.

The upshot is that a larger coefficient doesn't necessarily mean a stronger *p*-value. The *p*-value just indicates how likely you would be to get a coefficient that large by chance. And depending on the distribution of your data/response, you can actually be fairly likely to get large values by chance, so you can't in general get a relationship between coefficient size and p-values.

Now for two caveats to this:

- If your variables have *very* different units--like by a factor of $10^{10}$ or something--it can make it look numerically like your dataset exhibits [collinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity), which means you may encounter numerical problems when you fit your model. Rescaling the predictors can help with this.
- If you're using some types of regularized regression (e.g. [ridge regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) or [LASSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Lasso_method)), then smaller coefficients will be penalized less, so multiplying a variable by 10 and dividing its coefficient by 10 will make that coefficient more likely to be selected/have a higher value. This is why it's often advisable to center and scale your data when using these sorts of techniques.

Comment: A third caveat: If you transform the data say to "logarithmic units" then the P values may be different. Of course, that is more than a unit change, but some people get linear unit transforms mixed up with nonlinear transforms so I figured this note may help someone not make that mistake.

Comment: Good catch--thank you! I'm not used to thinking of a log transform as "scaling" or "changing units," but the OP could very well have meant that.

Comment: +1--but you seem to have lost the end of the text in the first caveat.

Comment: @BenKuhn: Thank you very much! I actually had some collinearity issue which I could fix relatively easily.

Comment: Could you explain why large differences in scale can make it look like your data has colinearity?