# The expectation of a function of the sample mean in terms of an expectation of a function of the variable $E[g(\bar{X}-\mu)] = h(n) \cdot E[f(X-\mu)]$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value

#### Example

The variance of the error of a sample mean can be expressed in terms of the variance of the distribution of the population that is sampled.

$$E[(\bar{X}-\mu)^2] = \frac{1}{n} \cdot E[(X-\mu)^2] $$

In this case, the expression on the right-hand side can be partitioned in a product of a function that is only dependent of $n$ and a function that is an expectation of some function of the variable.

#### Generalisations?

Which are other functions $g(x) \neq x^2$ for which we can write the expectation $E[g(\bar{X}-\mu)]$ as a product like below? What can we say about these functions?

$$E[g(\bar{X}-\mu)] = h(n) \cdot E[f(X-\mu)]$$

So in the example case we have $g(x) =x^2$ in which case $h(n) = 1/n$ and $f(x) = x^2$.

(to be clear: $f(x)$ is not a function that can change depending on $n$.)

<sup>**Background:** In this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/559834/164061) I use an expression of the variance of the error of the sample mean in terms of an expectation of the population distribution that is [computed with an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case) of the quantile function $E[f(X)] = \int_{\Omega}f(X(\omega)) dp(\Omega)$. The question remains open for which other cost functions we could use a similar construction.</sup>

Comment: For the 3rd central moment we can also partition the expression. Because we have [the additive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment#Properties). $$\mu_3(X+Y) = \mu_3(X) + \mu_3(Y)$$ from which follows $$\mu_3(\bar{X}) =\frac{1}{n} \mu_3(X)$$.

Comment: I made a mistake in the previous comment. We have $$\mu_3(\bar{X}) = \mu_3(  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} {X_i})  = n \mu_3(\frac{1}{n}  X) = n \left( \frac{1}{n}\right)^3 \mu_3( X) = \frac{1}{n^2} \mu_3(X)$$